# Website Scaling

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

So on this website I've been building I gotten to the point where I test to see what it looks like in other resolutions and browsers. The only problem that I have is with my navbar. The tabs in the nav bar get pushed down to the next line of the page. So my question is how can I scale it so that it fits with in the 960 desgin on all/most resolutions?

I've tried

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1">
```

but that doesn't work. 
http://www.chrhsink.net23.net

Comment: Didn't you tried [CSS3 media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/)?

Comment: To get he nav to fit you need to reduce the padding on the `a` to fit at its full width then use the media queries  to scale down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make it "responsive" somehow... Using media queries as stated by Log1c is an option. Maybe this post (http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-responsive-web) might give you a good idean on what needs to be done.